# Update facebook status from site

Tags: facebook, status

In my site page one text box and publish button.
When i clicked on button which is a text in text box its published on facebook as status.
For this update status user have to allow this application on facebook.
Once user allow this application whenever user clicked publish that text will update status of facebook.
and also user need not to login agian and agian to facebook. Its done internally

like update  facebook status from twitter.
I am new in php.
is there any easy solution?

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is looking for a working script: You can also use:

http://360percents.com/posts/php-curl-status-update-working-example/

Comment: link broken not available anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update the user status information you don't need to create a Facebook  application. You can do it with PHP Curl library. Look at the example here - http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1204

Comment: That works if users want to give you their actual Facebook credentials which they won't. You can however use Facebook Connect to achieve something like the OAuth method in Twitter...

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I saved this code in x.php and run.
But it doesn't work.it displays blank page.

is any error?
please help me.

Comment: hello,
I gave echo for each line.
It displays one by one output.
It shows login page of facebook then my home page .
But why doesn't it set status update?

above status update box it displays this line "We use security question to help identify you as the owner of your Facebook account if you ever need to write us for help."

I have not used security question.
is it need to set security question?

Whats the problem please tell me.
code is working but it doesn't set status.
How many time takes to update the status?
Please help. Its urgent!

Comment: sorry busy at work now - I will test the code and send it to you as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

There is this class http://www.barattalo.it/mini-bots-php-class/ that allows you also to post on a fan page wall with a small bot, without using the facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

Since the **offline_access** permission has been removed recently ([read about that here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/02/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)), you'll need to get a long-lived access_token. This will let you do status updates for your users on behalf of your applications for 60 days. After 60 days, you'll have to get your users to authenticate again, since your access token would be invalidated.

You can read about that here:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/