# Facebook status update through php

Tags: php, api, facebook, google-talk, chatbot

I want to develop a bot which will update the status of a facebook account using php.

Please guide me on this

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874512/update-facebook-status-from-site

Comment: This bot already exists: it connects to facebook, performs the login and then sets the status. You can find it here: > http://www.barattalo.it/2010/03/01/php-curl-bot-to-update-facebook-status/

Answer (score 3):

@Porkchop is correct, you will probably need the Facebook Connect API.  To update a users status on Facebook, you should look at the [Status.set](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Status.set) API call.

For coding a googletalk bot in php there are some articles that should get you started:

- [Twitter PHP Jabber Bot Tutorial](http://www.jazzychad.com/twitter/bots/)
- [Jabber Simple - A PHP library](http://www.thenullpointer.net/blog/jabber-simple-a-php-library)

But also consider using [IMified](http://www.imified.com/), which does a lot of the work of creating and running chat bots for you.

---

If all you are interested in is a simple way to update your Facebook status from you Google Talk status, you probably don't need to go to all that work - just install the '[Google Talk Status Synchronizer](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=33855239494)' facebook application.

Answer (score 1):

You could hire somebody to do it for cheap by outsourcing it, i mean thats what i do when i dont know code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are coding in PHP, I recommend using Jaxl (Jabber XMPP Library).
It supports bot authentication using X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM and updating facebook status should be a one line task using the library. http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL