# Get number of files in folder with AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I made a flash webpage with a file-upload system for uploading pdf's to a subfolder in the same folder where the swf is hosted. I want to make a very simple system to count the number of files in that folder from inside the AS3 of the main webpage (with the purpose of displaying it somewhere in the flash page..). I still haven't found a straight answer on how to do it (or if it's even possible). I think that maybe i have to use an additional php script to count the files..

Any idea is welcome! Thx in advance!

Comment: If you can use an external script, then coding a PHP script and invoking it seems like a viable solution to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133266/flash-calling-a-php-function

Comment: Uploading requires a data receiver at server side, while SWF is run at client side. You should definitely use PHP for such a script.

Comment: Your swf won't be able to do that since it's a front end technology, only the server side can do that with any server side language available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a server-side script. For example, using PHP you can use [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to read the files and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output it as JSON. For example:

```
// scandir.php
echo json_encode(scandir("path/to/dir"));
```

Then you simply load the JSON from AS3 using `URLLoader`. For example:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("http://path/to/scandir.php"));
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
function complete(e:Event):void {
        var files:Array = JSON.parse(urlLoader.data);
        trace(files.length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i think i'm doing this in the site, tested it yesterday and i believe it's the easiest way. Thanks a lot again!